# Mathematica 12.1 not starting

Tags: kernel-startup

I have installed Mathematica 12.1 on my Windows 7 desktop and also activated it via the Mathematica Kernel option in the startup menu. But when I try to start it normally I always get the same error which is attached below. It tells the Fault Module file is KERNELBASE.dl. Can anyone suggest me a quick and easy way to get Mathematica going on my PC?
[image: Error image]

Comment: First, make sure Windows 7 is 100% up to date.  All optional updates, etc...  If that doesn't help, then you'll probably need to set the environment variable MATHEMATICA_D3D_VERSION=9.

Comment: How to set the variable MATHEMATICA_D3D_VERSION=9? Can you explain in bit detail

Comment: Control Panel > System > Advanced System Settings, then click on the Environment Variables button.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked. Now it is running smoothly. Can you also explain to me what does that command " MATHEMATICA_D3D_VERSION=9" mean? And what is the purpose of this command? Was it a problem with my computer?

Comment: Simply put:  12.1.0 doesn't like your machine.  Specifically how we are using Direct3D11.  What you just did was tell the FrontEnd to use Direct3D9 instead (which is what we used up through 12.0).  It should be fixed in a future update.