# Mathematica Not Loading

Tags: warning-messages

Mathematica 12 was working fine, but after recent updates (Nvidia drivers and Windows 10) the kernel will load happily, but when trying to load Mathematica the screens hang and I'm greeted with a blank white panel in their place.

AMD CPU, NVIDIA 3080 GPU, all latest drivers/updates installed.

I suspect it's maybe a DirectX issue from the thread below, but can't quite pin down how to resurrect it.  I've reinstalled Mathematica and still no joy.

I've tried to force it to run in difference DirectX versions, but I'm getting the same problem.

I wasn't sure of a couple of parts within this potential answer, how to specifically edit the Environment Variables.

[Mathematica 12.1 not starting](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/219498/mathematica-12-1-not-starting)

Comment: This seems like a question for Wolfram support.

Comment: Perhaps, I was hoping that it may be a common problem and there was a magic DirectX deactivate button or something similar that users were aware of.

Answer (score 2):

Answering the original question in case someone else has a similar problem as this has been confirmed by Wolfram as a known issue.

Setting the default printer on a Windows 10 machine to the Microsoft XPS Document Writer allowed Mathematica 12 to load on a Windows 10 machine again.  I cleared caches etc but no avail, as soon as I set the default printer then Mathematica was able to load again.

Comment: Makes sense... hum...